# TabLayout and bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, bottomnavigationview

[image: image to depict the question]

Hello, I have searched possible ways of implementing something like what can be seen in the image above, but couldn't find any help. I want to create a `TabLayout` and bottom navigation, such that the `TabLayout` is bound to the first bottom icon, and the second bottom icon is bound to another `TabLayout`.

I will be glad if you can help with examples or sample code. I am still more of a beginner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a beginner, you need to have a mindset that a problem can be split to more simpler problems by applying [Divide and conquer algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm).

For your case, you need to split the problem of TabLayout and bottom navigation. The problem after split are:

1. **TabLayout**
2. **ViewPager**
3. ***Combining*** TabLayout with ViewPager
4. **Bottom Navigation**
5. ***Combining*** TabLayout with ViewPager and Bottom Navigation.

First, you need to make a working TabLayout. Visit [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html). Then learn about ViewPager: Using [ViewPager for Screen Slides](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) and [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). Then [combine them](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout).

Then you need to learn about Bottom Navigation at [Bottom Navigation Views](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Bottom-Navigation-Views)

After that you need to find how to integrate the Bottom Navigation with TabLayout and ViewPager.

Sample project with tab:
https://github.com/eure/citrus

[Plaid](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid) should be interesting for you.

Comment: am so grateful.

Comment: I have gone through all that, the main issue is how to integrate the Bottom Navigation with the TabLayout and ViewPager

Comment: You just need to set selected page in viewpager and tab layout when clicking bottom navigation, vice versa

Comment: I'm sorry for not giving a clear explanation for you. What I mean is, in view pager there is a method to select the current view pager item which is viewPager.setCurrentItem. In the [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) there is a method to select the item which is [setSelectedItemId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#setSelectedItemId(int)). So you just need to select the related item in view page whenever you click BottomNavigationView, vice versa.